# Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I am using asp.net core, razor engine, and entity framework.  I am getting this error when I try to run my code in VS code using dotnet watch run.  Here is the full error.

```
Project c-login (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
A JSON parsing exception occurred in [/Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/c#/asp.net/entity/c-
login/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/c-login.deps.json]: * Line 1, Column 2 Syntax error: Malformed
token
Error initializing the dependency resolver: An error occurred while parsing /Users/aaronmk2/D
esktop/CodingDojo/c#/asp.net/entity/c-login/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/c-login.deps.json
[DotNetWatcher] fail: dotnet exit code: 139
[DotNetWatcher] info: Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
```

Has anyone seen this error before?  What is the workaround?

Comment: Does it run without errors if you just run "dotnet run" ?

Comment: @RickHodder, no I get the same error when I try dotnet run

Comment: I would lint the json file it is talking about to see if there's an error: you could paste it into http://jsonlint.com/ .

Comment: Could you share what was wrong so that if anyone else runs into it, they will find the answer here?  Was I right about the json?

Comment: I just needed to delete my bin file and ran dotnet restore and dotnet watch run and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, after trying everything I figure out that it was because of the corrupted certificate. For some reason my certificate got corrupted so, I had to delete the old one and generate a new one.
To generate:

```
dotnet dev-certs https
```

To trust:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you just have to successfully build your project and restart the server. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error but I had something else wrong. The issue that I had was that I was trying to connect to a server in my appsettings.json file using Microsoft credentials such as using `Server=(LocalDB)`. After updating it to the MacOS way of connecting to a DB, it worked.

I went from

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=ShirtDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

To

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,*port number*;Database=MyDB;User ID=sa;Password=******"
```

Comment: Please can you explain how this is related to the question.

Comment: @MikePoole I added a sentence to the beginning of my answer so I hope it helps. The main question was "Has anyone seen this error before? What is the workaround?" I received the same error. I'm providing the "workaround" that I used in case someone had a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although this was already solved I wanted to give another solution since I couldn't find much on this specific error.

I had a similar issue using MySQL that looked like this:

```
A JSON parsing exception occurred in [C:\foo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\foo.deps.json]: * Line 1, Column 2 Syntax error: Malformed token
Error initializing the dependency resolver: An error occurred while parsing: C:\foo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\foo.deps.json
```

I ended up dropping my schema and removing all my previous migrations and then it started working fine. My best theory is that something I did to my models caused it. Hopefully, this helps someone out.